# Setting XFCE-Session as default

Tags: xfce, login-screen

How can I set ´Xfce-Session´ as default in the session selection during the login procedure?
Here is my ubuntu version information:

```
# lsb_release -a
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 21.04
Codename:   hirsute
```

- Google and Co. didn´t want to help
- editing the users setting in the folder /var/lib/AccountsService/users didn´t work

Comment: The last session you selected during login normally is remembered, so will be the default for any subsequent login. Or is that not what you specifically ask? If not, then please edit your question to clarify.

Comment: Ubuntu 21.04 (along with all flavors) is *End-of-Life* and thus unsupported on this site (https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic), and many other Ubuntu sites, unless your question is specific to moving to a supported release of Ubuntu. https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2022/01/21/ubuntu-21-04-hirsute-hippo-end-of-life-reached-on-january-20-2022/  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EOLUpgrades

Comment: "Guiverc" is right. 21.04 is past end of life. You should upgrade immediately to 21.10 and thence to 22.04, to get onto a current, supported version.

Comment: @LiamProven just FYI:  but the *release-upgrade* path to 21.10 was gone the moment [21.10 reached EOL](https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2022/07/19/ubuntu-21-10-impish-indri-end-of-life-reached-on-july-14-2022/) as the [ubuntu-release-upgrade tools](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubuntu-release-upgrader) check https://changelogs.ubuntu.com/meta-release which has a "*Supported = 0*" against 21.10 placed against it as the *Ubuntu Release Team* declared the release EOL.  The *release-upgrade* would need to be forced & not performed in the QA-tested & *supported* methods..

Comment: More fyi:    I'd still try it if was me & hope it'd upgrade me to 22.04; nothing is lost except a few seconds.. if it was me, I'd just *upgrade via re-install* which I know works with Ubuntu and *flavors* pretty well, as I do this rather regularly to upgrade packages on systems achieving a QA-test install (non-destructive) & upgrade packages at the same time using *daily* images..

Answer (score 1):

Use this command (you may need sudo):

```
update-alternatives --config x-session-manager
```

then you'll be prompted to select your desired DE like this:

```
  Selection    Path                      Priority   Status
------------------------------------------------------------
* 0            /usr/bin/startlxde         50        auto mode
  1            /usr/bin/lxsession         49        manual mode
  2            /usr/bin/openbox-session   40        manual mode
  3            /usr/bin/startlxde         50        manual mode
  4            /usr/bin/startxfce4        50        manual mode
  5            /usr/bin/xfce4-session     40        manual mode

Press <enter> to keep the current choice[*], or type selection number: 5
```

hope that helps :)